# Analytical solution for optimization problem

Tags: optimization, analytical

Is there an analytical solution for the following optimization problem:

$b, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (vectors), $b^* = \arg min_{b \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(b)$, where $f(b) = ||b-y||_{2}^{2} + \varphi ||b||_{1}$ where $\varphi > 0$

Its so close to $L_1$ regression, but I cant solve this even in that way.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  It would all depend on what "$\varphi$" means: that detail is essential for answering your question.

Comment: $\phi$ is a constant which greater than 0

Comment: Ah--so $\phi$ is not a function.  This problem is called the "Lasso."  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lasso+closed+form for the general problem.  Since yours is so specific, it is plausible it would have a specific answer (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Using vector math re-writing your problem, also replacing b with X:
$$f(X)=(X-Y)^T(X-Y)+\varphi |X|^T 1$$
First Order Conditions:
$$f(X)'=0$$
$$2(X-Y)+\varphi \space\mathrm{sign}(X)=0$$
Solution:
$$X=Y-\mathrm{sign}(X)\varphi/2$$

- when $|Y_i|\ge\varphi/2$:
  $$X=Y-\mathrm{sign}(Y)\varphi /2$$
- when $|Y_i|<\varphi/2$:
  $$X=0$$

Comment: +1.  But what does "F.O.C." mean?

Comment: @whuber, I spelled it out, 1st order conditions